# Update spring boot CRUD not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf, crud

I'm a newbie on spring-boot and I'm building this tool for learning purposes based on documentation and some tutorials I've found. So, I've built some code using CRUD repositories extending from package org.springframework.data.repository. I've come to the part of UPDATE a record using this RESTservice Impl

```
public boolean modifyVacancy(Vacancy vacancy){
    boolean passedProcessFlow = false;
    if(vacancyRepository.exists(vacancy.getIdVacancy())){
        vacancyRepository.save(vacancy);
        passedProcessFlow = true;
    }
    return passedProcessFlow;
}
```

which is being called from the Controller here:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/vacancies/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String editVacancy(@PathVariable Integer id, Model model,
                          @ModelAttribute("vacancyEdit") Vacancy vacancy){
    System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<IT PASSED THROUGH HERE>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    //modelAndView.setViewName("vacancies");
    vacancyService.modifyVacancy(vacancy);

    return "redirect:vacancies";
}
```

And last but not least my thymeleaf html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script src="../static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link th:href="@{static/css/login.css}"
          rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />        
    <script src="../static/js/login.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootbox.js/4.4.0/bootbox.min.js"></script>
    <link href="../static/css/guru.css"
          th:href="@{css/guru.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    <link href="../static/css/guru.css"
          th:href="@{css/guru.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>

    <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {

              var btnOpen = $('#btnOpen'),
                  btnOpenEdit = $('#btnOpenEdit'),
                  btnOnInterviewEdit = $('#btnOnInterviewEdit'),
                  btnOnInterview = $('#btnOnInterview'),
                  btnCloseEdit = $('#btnClosedEdit')
                  btnClose = $('#btnClosed')

                  $("#vacancyStatus").val("1");



              $("#btnOpen").click(function () {
                $("#vacancyStatus").val("1");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-info')
                    btnOnInterview.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnClose.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

              $("#btnOpenEdit").click(function () {
                $("#vacancyStatusEdit").val("1");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-info')
                    btnOnInterviewEdit.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnCloseEdit.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

                $("#btnOnInterview").click(function () {
                    $("#vacancyStatus").val("2");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-warning')
                    btnOpen.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnClose.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

                $("#btnOnInterviewEdit").click(function () {
                    $("#vacancyStatusEdit").val("2");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-warning')
                    btnOpenEdit.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnCloseEdit.removeClass('btn-danger').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

                $("#btnClosed").click(function () {
                    $("#vacancyStatus").val("3");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger')
                    btnOnInterview.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnOpen.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

                $("#btnClosedEdit").click(function () {
                    $("#vacancyStatusEdit").val("3");
                    $(this).toggleClass('btn-default btn-danger')
                    btnOnInterviewEdit.removeClass('btn-warning').addClass('btn-default')
                    btnOpenEdit.removeClass('btn-info').addClass('btn-default')
                    });

                 $('#search-form').submit(function(){
                      var formAction = $("#selectsearch").val() == "people" ? "user" : "content";
                      $("#search-form").attr("action", "/search/" + formAction);
                    });

                $('.editButton').on('click', function() {
                        // Get the record's ID via attribute
                        var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/vacancies/'+ id,
                            method: 'GET'
                        }).success(function(response) {
                            // Populate the form fields with the data returned from server
                            $('#vacancyEditForm')
                                .find('[id="idVacancyEdit"]').val(id).end()
                                .find('[id="positionTitleEdit"]').val(response.jobPositionTitle).end()
                                .find('[id="skillsDescriptionEdit"]').val(response.jobPositionSkillDescription).end()
                                .find('[id="vacancySlotsEdit"]').val(response.vacancySlots).end()
                                .find('[id="vacancyStatusEdit"]').val(response.vacancyState).end()
                                .prop("action", "/vacancies/edit/"+id)

                            // Show the dialog
                            bootbox
                                .dialog({
                                    title: 'Edit Vacancy',
                                    message: $('#vacancyEditForm'),
                                    show: false // We will show it manually later
                                })
                                .on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
                                    $('#vacancyEditForm')
                                        .show()                             // Show the login form
                                        //.formValidation('resetForm'); // Reset form
                                })
                                .on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
                                    // Bootbox will remove the modal (including the body which contains the login form)
                                    // after hiding the modal
                                    // Therefor, we need to backup the form
                                    $('#vacancyEditForm').trigger("reset");
                                    $('#vacancyEditForm').hide().appendTo('body');
                                    //$('#vacancyEditForm').hide();
                                })
                                .modal('show');
                        });
                    });





        });
    </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>

    <title>Vacancies List</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div >
            <h2>Vacancy List</h2>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <div class="col col-xs-6 text-left">
                <a  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalVacancyInput"  class="btn icon-btn btn-success" href="#"><span class="glyphicon btn-glyphicon glyphicon-plus img-circle text-success"></span>Add New Vacancy</a>
            </div>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Skills Description</th>
                    <th>View</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>

                </tr>
                <tr th:each="vacancyO : ${vacancies}">
                    <td th:text="${vacancyO.idVacancy}">Vacancy Id</td>
                    <td th:text="${vacancyO.jobPositionTitle}">Job Title</td>
                    <td th:text="${vacancyO.jobPositionSkillDescription}">price</td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-success" th:href="@{'/vacancy/id='+${vacancyO.idVacancy}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">View</span></a></td>
                    <!--td><a class="btn btn-warning" th:attr="data-id=${vacancyO.idVacancy}" name="editButton" th:href="@{'/vacancy/edit/id='+${vacancyO.idVacancy}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</span></a></td-->
                    <td><button class="btn btn-warning editButton" th:attr="data-id=${vacancyO.idVacancy}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Edit</span></button></td>
                    <td><a class="btn btn-danger" th:href="@{'/vacancy/delete/id='+${vacancyO.idVacancy}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Delete</span></a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="modalVacancyInput" class= "modal fade in" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title">Vacancy</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form th:action="@{/vacancies}" id="vacancyForm" role="form" method="post"  th:object="${vacancy}" class="form-horizontal">
                            <fieldset>
                                <!-- Text input-->
                                <!--div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idVacancy">Id Vacancy</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="idVacancy" name="idVacancy" type="text" placeholder="Id. Vacancy" class="form-control input-md"/>
                                        <span class="help-block">help</span>  
                                    </div>
                                </div-->

                                <!-- Text input-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="positionTitle">Position Title</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="positionTitle" th:field="*{jobPositionTitle}" name="positionTitle" type="text" placeholder="Position title" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>
                                        <span class="help-block">help</span>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Textarea -->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="skillsDescription">Skills Description</label>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">                     
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="skillsDescription" th:field="*{jobPositionSkillDescription}" name="skillsDescription">Detail the required skills</textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Text input-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vacancySlots">Positions to open</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <input id="vacancySlots" th:field="*{vacancySlots}" name="vacancySlots" type="number" placeholder="1" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>
                                        <span class="help-block">help</span>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <input value="1"  type="hidden" id="vacancyStatus" th:field="*{vacancyState}"/>
                                <!-- Text input-->
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Status</label>  
                                    <div class="btn-group-lg" align="left"> 
                                        <button type="button" id="btnOpen" value="Opened" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" id="btnOnInterview"  value="OnInterview" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i></button>
                                        <button type="button" id="btnClosed"  value="Closed" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                            data-dismiss="modal">
                                        Close
                                    </button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Save changes
                                    </button>
                                </div>



                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>


                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->

    <div id="modalVacancyEdit" class= "modal fade in" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title">Vacancy</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form id="vacancyEditForm" role="form" th:method="POST"  th:object="${vacancyEdit}" class="form-horizontal">
                        <fieldset>
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="idVacancyEdit">Id Vacancy</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="idVacancyEdit" th:field="*{idVacancy}" name="idVacancy" type="text" placeholder="Id. Vacancy" class="form-control input-md" disabled="true"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="positionTitleEdit">Position Title</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="positionTitleEdit" th:field="*{jobPositionTitle}" name="positionTitle" type="text" placeholder="Position title" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>
                                    <span class="help-block">help</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Textarea -->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="skillsDescriptionEdit">Skills Description</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" id="skillsDescriptionEdit" th:field="*{jobPositionSkillDescription}" name="skillsDescription">Detail the required skills</textarea>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="vacancySlotsEdit">Positions to open</label>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <input id="vacancySlotsEdit" th:field="*{vacancySlots}" name="vacancySlots" type="number" placeholder="1" class="form-control input-md" required=""/>
                                    <span class="help-block">help</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input value="1"  type="hidden" id="vacancyStatusEdit" th:field="*{vacancyState}"/>
                            <!-- Text input-->
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Status</label>
                                <div class="btn-group-lg" align="left">
                                    <button type="button" id="btnOpenEdit" value="Opened" class="btn btn-info btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" ></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" id="btnOnInterviewEdit"  value="OnInterview" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></i></button>
                                    <button type="button" id="btnClosedEdit"  value="Closed" class="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></button>
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
                                        data-dismiss="modal">
                                    Close
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Save changes
                                </button>
                            </div>



                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>


            </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
```

I'm getting it to run the create nicely, but when I come to the part of using the button edit (for editing a record), that displays a bootstrap modal that wraps form "vacancyEditForm", and the javascript found in the previous sample changes the form.action to some path which should be captured by my Controller in editVacancy method...............but is not!! and probably is something dumb I'm missing but I'm clueless now....any thoughts?

Comment: there is not action for you modalVacancyEdit form.

Comment: I added it in the javascript using jquery with  .prop("action", "/vacancies/edit/"+id). Besides when I run the DOM inspector in Chrome, the form has its right action being set.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS code is doing a GET, the Spring Code is listening for a POST. Thus the controller action will not get triggered. Change the JS to do a POST.

Comment: Hi John! I appreciate your time for making a contribution. The AJAX javascript does a GET just for merely populate the modal. I already changed it to POST and is not even showing the modal........was it there where you are suggesting the change, or somewhere else? The other issue is that the modal form's method is POST......... :'(